# Will "$!" reliably return the correct ID with "&"?

Tags: bash, background-process, parallelism, thread, wait

In my tests, I always get the correct result so far with this:

```
[fabian@manjaro ~]$ sleep 10 & echo $!
[1] 302657
302657
```

But `sleep` and `echo` are getting executed simultaneously here, so I would expect that it can sometimes happen that `echo` executes before the value of `$!` is set properly. Can this happen? Why doesn't it so far for me?

My ultimate goal: Execute two tasks in parallel and then wait for both before moving on. The current plan is to use something like `foo & bar; wait $!; baz`. Will this always work or can it sometimes wait for an arbitrary older background process (or nothing at all, if `$!` is empty)?

Comment: I'm not sure which tag(s) out of [tag:parallelism], [tag:thread] and [tag:multithreading] to use. Don't they mean mostly the same, especially as tags?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So

```
sleep 10 & echo $!
```

is two commands

```
sleep 10 & 
echo $!
```

That they're on the same line doesn't change this.

So the shell will `fork()` a new process and put the process ID of the new process into `$!`.  Then the new process will run the `sleep` and the other process will run the `echo`.

So you can be sure `$!` will always hold the PID of the new process, even if that process fails; it's the result of the `fork()`.

Answer (score 1):

In order to achieve this:

> My ultimate goal: Execute two tasks in parallel and then wait for both before moving on.

It is enough to include both commands into a script, send them to background (`&`) so that will start immediately and run in parallel, and `wait` for them, without capturing their pids and explicitly wait for them.

```
task1 &
task2 &
wait
echo both tasks finished
```

From the posix manual of `wait`:

> If  the  wait  utility is invoked with no operands, it shall wait until all process IDs known to the
> invoking shell have terminated and exit with a zero exit status.

Comment: Interesting. So I could also do `task1 & task2; wait; echo`, it would do the same, right? And also `A & B; C; wait; D`, where C would wait for B and D would wait for A and C, but nothing else on anything else.

Comment: `D` will wait for anything before the `wait` statement, for `A`,`B` and `C`. Based on that, you can do almost everything in a script (without playing with the pids).